# Monitor number of clicks that each list item getting

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
 <li>box</li>
 <li>box</li>
 <li>box</li>
 <li>box</li>
 <li>box</li>
</ul>


$(function(){
  var counter = 0;
  $('li').click(function(){
  if(counter > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
 });
});
```

I have something like this. When list item click increment my count but if this list item is new so has ever clicked then start incerement by zero.

https://jsfiddle.net/pzzzy97v/

Comment: So where's your problem? What does the code do? What doesn't it do that it should?

Comment: Where are you showing the incremented count? Can you add a fiddle and show the issue?

Comment: that's starts every time 1. like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pzzzy97v/. 

I want to reset when click li and after start again increment like 1-2-3-4-5-6

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pzzzy97v/1/  check this fiddle, is this what you are expecting

Comment: Your question text wording is not completely clear.  Do you want to know how many times each `li` has been clicked ("monitor number of clicks") or they have all been clicked once and only once and reset if one is clicked twice ("but if this item is new so has *ever* [been] clicked then [re]start increment [at] zero")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to see the click is on the same element or not.

## RESET COUNTER

```js
$(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  $('li').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
      counter++;
    else {
      $('li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      counter = 1;
    }
    $('span').html(counter);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
</ul>
<span></span>
```

## COUNTER FOR EACH ITEM

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').data('count',0);
  $('li').click(function() {
    var thisCount = $(this).data('count');
    thisCount++;
    $(this).data('count',thisCount);
    $('span').html(thisCount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
  <li>box</li>
</ul>
<span></span>
```

Comment: thank you for interest. i share my jsfiddle example can you check?

Comment: @JohnReese this is a working example. click on "Run code snippet" button.

Comment: "Monitor number of clicks that **each list item** getting" - Your solution does not fulfill the bold part of the requirement

Comment: @Andreas a frequent problem with SO - the question title and the question text do not match.  In this case, this answer matches the question text while the question title only vaguely matches the question text (or as I interpret the question text... but reading it again... maybe not... it's not very clear)

Comment: @Andreas anyway I've updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this array trick will do what you need. You can try the following code:

```
$(function(){
   var liClickCnt = new Array();
    $('li').click(function(){
        var counter = 0;
        var liIndex = $(this).index();
        liClickCnt[liIndex] = (liClickCnt[liIndex]) ? ++liClickCnt[liIndex] : ++counter;        
       $('span').html(liClickCnt[liIndex]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the question title into count [see what I did there?], you could add a data attribute to each `li` to record how many times it's been clicked:

```
$(function() {
    // set them all on startup for clarity
    $("li").data("clickcount", 0);
    $("li").click(function() {
        // increment click count on each
        $(this).data("clickcount", $(this).data("clickcount") + 1);
    });
});
```

This matches from the question:

- monitor number of clicks that each list item [is] getting
- when list item click increment [my] count
- but if this list item is new so has [never]ever [been] clicked then start increment [for that list item] [at] zero.

Assuming a typo on "this is new so ever been clicked" to mean "this is new so never been clicked"